# how to resolve an error when merging 2 data frames using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I am trying to join 2 tables df1 which has 2 columns(DATA_DUMP_DT, A) and df2 which as 2 columns(DATA_DUMP_DT,B) where DATA_DUMP_DT column is of dtype 'datetime64[ns]'

### df1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data_Dump_dt':pd.to_datetime(['7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020',
'7/31/2020','7/31/2020','8/31/2020','8/31/2020','8/31/2020','8/31/2020','8/31/2020','8/31/2020','8/31/2020','8/31/2020',
'8/31/2020']),
                    'A':[0,1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,0,1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10]
                    
                    })
df1 = df1[['Data_Dump_dt','A']]
df1
```

### df2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data_Dump_dt':pd.to_datetime(['7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020',                     '8/31/2020','8/31/2020','8/31/2020','8/31/2020','8/31/2020','8/31/2020','8/31/2020','8/31/2020']),
                    'B':[0,1,2,3,4,8,9,10,0,1,2,3,4,8,9,10]
                    
                    })
df2 = df2[['Data_Dump_dt','B']]
df2
```

[image: DF1]

[image: DF2]

when joined **df_final2 = df1.join(df2,how='inner',on='DATA_DUMP_DT')** it throws error **ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['DATA_DUMP_DT'], dtype='object')**

when done some research I found this error comes where there is no matching between df1 and df2 column **['DATA_DUMP_DT']** but my data has dates as common

required output is as below. can some one help me on this please.

[image: Output]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of data/code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, try to post a [mre]. Specifically, your question asserts a behavior that isn't how pandas works. If you can provide a reproducible example, that would be really helpful! Otherwise, this is likely to be closed as not reproducible. Thanks!

Comment: The dates are not unique. If you had one of each in each data frame it would join. However, since you have multiple of the same date, the program doesn't know 'which' July 30th to join.  If you want them in order, than you could add an index column and say join where index and date match (or something along those lines).

Comment: Use `df1['group'] = df1.groupby(['Data_Dump_dt']).cumcount()
df2['group'] = df2.groupby(['Data_Dump_dt']).cumcount()
result = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['Data_Dump_dt', 'group']).drop('group', axis=1)`

Comment: Hi @jezrael this solution didnt work well , when checked the result for the date '2020-07-31' col A dosnet consist of value 10

Comment: Hi @jezrael                                                   
 df1['group'] = df1.groupby(['Data_Dump_dt']).cumcount() df2['group'] = df2.groupby(['Data_Dump_dt']).cumcount() result = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer' on=['Data_Dump_dt', 'group']).drop('group', axis=1) is working good. Thanks for the help